# How to add null value to lookup column using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, custom-list, lookup-column, multiple-values

I have **Custom list** in which i have one **Multi lookup column** in that user select data from front end then i have to add that data in **lookup column**.

But if user not select any data then i have to add null or blank.

So how can i do this.

I am using **REST API** for `POST Request`.

Any Help highly Appreciated.

Comment: Just do not specify the lookup column in the request body. That's all

Comment: that i know .but have other value also in body. i have to create two request body if it null then without it and if have value then other.

Comment: i am thinking like if i pass "" or "null" or other so i didnt need to create multiple request body as per condition.

Comment: You can pass `null` also. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In multi lookup column i have passed value like below and its works.

```
"[Internal Name of lookup the column]Id": {'results':[]}
```

In single item look up you have to passed like below as per **@AtishDipongkor** Answer

```
"[Internal Name of lookup the column]Id": null
```

Comment: That means your lookup column allows multiple value. You have not mention in the question!

Comment: @AtishDipongkor sorry i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 5):

Just do not specify lookup column in request body or set lookup value to `null`

```
{
"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.[List Name]ListItem"},
"Title": "[Title]",
"[Internal Name of lookup the column]Id": null
}
```

Comment: if i want textfield as null then  how can i pass  null??